# How to remove duplication in different methods in a class?

Tags: android

I have a class which provides several api methods ,say methodA, methodB,methodC...,

these method signatures are APIs that cannot be changed.
in each of these methods, i have quite similar structures :

1) step1: same for every methods

2) step2: same for every methods

3) step3: different stuff todo

is there a way that I can remove the duplications in these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have similar methods in the same class you can create an auxiliar private method with the same code.

If you have similar methods in differents classes then you can do "template method" design pattern. Here a "template method" structure example:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    ...

    /* A template method. Shared code */
    public void similarCode() {
    // same for every methods
    }
    ...
}

public class Subclass1 extends Superclass {
    ...
    public void something() {

        // different stuff todo
        super.similarCode ();
        // different stuff todo
    }
    ...
}

public class Subclass2 extends Superclass {
    ...
    public void something() {

        // different stuff todo
        super.similarCode ();
        // different stuff todo
    }
    ...
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is quite a good point. I am working on that to abstract the process of every api into a command class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another method that performs step1 and step2, and just call it whenever needed. You don't have to repeat it.Pieces of identical code should be replaced with a single method Take a look at this [post](http://geekswithblogs.net/chrisfalter/archive/2008/03/07/refactor-to-dry.aspx).

Also, you can look at this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/107458/how-to-remove-duplicate-code-in-general).

Comment: yes that is better. But this is not what I want, for in every api method there is still the duplication of same method invocation

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Alex's reply.
I did the refactor by below process （command pattern）:

1:extract each api method into a command class xxxCommand

2:make a super class BaseApiCommand. move the duplication part into the constructor , and make the similar part into abstract method, which needs to be implemented in the concrete command class.

3:keep a HashMap to keep the commands instance: HashMap

4:in the place where old api logic exists, just call below:
  commands.get("name").execute(.....);

That is all. The duplication is removed with a command pattern.

Comment: down vote for what? Please give some better advice if you have suggestions please.